# Applying the styles to the CSV File using Powershell or c#

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm Creating a CSV file from XML file using powershell and would like to apply the few things for the CSV file:

1. Filter for the Header (Not filtering of rows in code)
2. Apply the colour to the Header row
3. Freeze the top row of the CSV File
4. Creating multiple sheets

MS office will not be installed on the server, so I need suggestions without using ComObject.

If solution is there in C# Please suggest I will convert the code to Powershell.

Code for CSV file generation::

```
$xmlFilePaths = @("D:\\IntegrationTests.xml", "D:\\Test.xml")
$excelFilePath = "D:\\Test.csv"

function CreateExcelFromXML($xmlFilePaths, $excelFilePath)
{
    foreach($xmlFilePath in $xmlFilePaths)
    {
        [xml]$xml = Get-Content $xmlFilePath

        $xml.SelectNodes('//test-case') |
        Select-Object @{n='ASSEMBLY';e={$_.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.name}},
                    @{n='SOLUTION';e={$_.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.name}},
                    @{n='PROJECT';e={$_.ParentNode.ParentNode.name}},
                    @{n='CLASS';e={$_.ParentNode.name}},
                    @{n='METHOD';e={$_.methodname}},
                    @{n='RUN STATUS';e={$_.runstate}},
                    @{n='SEED';e={$_.seed}},
                    @{n='STATUS';e={$_.result}},
                    @{n='DURATION';e={$_.duration}},
                    @{n='ASSERTS';e={$_.asserts}} | Export-Csv $excelFilePath -Append -NoType
    }
}

CreateExcelFromXML $xmlFilePaths $excelFilePath
```

Comment: Are does those xml always have the same structure? Is this structure convertible to a flat csv?

Comment: It's impossible to store filtering and text formatting in CSV file.

Comment: Yes, this XML will always have the same structure.

Comment: CSV's are flat data files. By definition you __cannot__ do this with them. If you want to create actual XLSX documents with a COM object you will need to rely on 3rd party libraries like those used in [Export-Excel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel)

Comment: Hi @Matt, I have the solution by using the Com Objects without using any third party libraries.

Comment: Ah. There is a typo in my comment. I meant _without_  as you said _twice_ that you would do this ___without using ComObject___. So if you do not want a COM solution then you need 3rd party as vanilla PowerShell cannot realistically do this.

Comment: Import-Excel / Export-Excel by dfinke doesn't use the Excel Com Object - it uses EPPlus, which is a .NET wrapper for OpenXml API

Comment: CSV means Comma Separated Values. It is text that are separated with values. CSV do not store any type of formatting. It sounds like what you are looking for is EXCEL xlsx or xls files. Which are completely different then CSV.

Comment: You can export to Excel using the [PSExcel](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSExcel) module, it will also do all the formatting you wanted. MSOffice is not required as it has its own libraries for excel file handling... The documentation is good and covers how to use it.

Comment: Hi @JamesC., Thank you for your answer. Please update your comment in Answer section, so that i will mark it as answer(Will be useful for others too in a glance) and will upvote(Unable to upvote comment as i have less reputation score)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PSExcel module](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSExcel) is my go-to module for Excel, it can import/export Excel files and also do all the formatting you wanted.

MS Office is not required with it as it has its own libraries for Excel file handling. The documentation is good and covers how to use it.